# Reduce space between multiple minted inputs in a single listing

Tags: listings, minted

I've created a listing with multiple code blocks using the `\inputminted` command And want to reduce the space between the blocks.

A minimal working example is given here:

```tex
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\usepackage[chapter]{minted}
\usemintedstyle{friendly}
\setminted{%
  bgcolor=lightgray,
  linenos
}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
\begin{listing}
    \inputminted{cpp}{helloworld.cpp}
    \inputminted{cpp}{helloworld.cpp}
    \caption{Example}
    \label{code}
\end{listing}
\end{document}
```

And `helloworld.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The generated output is:

[image: Example for multiple minted inputs in a single listing.]

I could reset the line numbers inside a `minted` environment. That way I could possibly implement an `.h` and a `.cpp` file. However I don't know how to do that with `inputminted`. A small distance between the blocks would be my desired solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between two consecutive `\inputminted`, several glue items are added

```
.....\glue 6.0 plus 2.0 minus 2.0
.....\glue(\baselineskip) 13.6
.....\glue 6.0 plus 2.0 minus 2.0
.....\glue(\baselineskip) 7.6
.....\vbox(6.0+0.0)x0.0
```

Indeed, if I try

```
\inputminted{cpp}{\jobname.cpp}

\vspace{-\medskipamount}
\vspace{-2\baselineskip}
\vspace{0.4pt}% just to show a very small white space

\inputminted{cpp}{\jobname.cpp}
```

I get

[image]

I suggest a macro `\betweenminted` which you can use to decide the amount of vertical space.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.cpp}
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[chapter]{minted}

\usemintedstyle{friendly}
\setminted{
  bgcolor=lightgray,
  linenos
}

\newcommand{\betweenminted}[1]{%
  \par\vspace{-\medskipamount}\vspace{-2\baselineskip}%
  \vspace{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}

\inputminted{cpp}{\jobname.cpp}

\betweenminted{\medskipamount}

\inputminted{cpp}{\jobname.cpp}

    \caption{Example}
    \label{code}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Production note:** I changed the name of the input file just not to clobber my files.